How to use GitLab CI to test submodules that have different dependencies than the parent module?
I have created a contrib module that adds an entity type.
I then created a submodule that adds a JSON-RPC endpoint to enable creating entities of the parent module using JSON-RPC.
This submodule depends on the JSON-RPC module, but the parent module does not (some people might want to use REST or just create entities in the UI).
The submodule is stored in a submodules/ directory of the parent module and has its own composer.json that requires drupal/jsonrpc.
When I push to drupal.org, GitLab CI runs a phpstan scan and phpunit tests for the submodule, but it ignores the submodule's composer.json and so everything fails because the JSON-RPC module does not get installed.
What is the correct way to fix this (install a dependency of a submodule when running tests for the module)?  Do I need to modify the test configuration for the submodule somehow, or should I add submodule dependencies as require-dev in the parent module's composer.json?

Composer doesn’t have an equivalent concept to submodules, or Drupal modules being installed or otherwise, it just knows about packages.
If some code in your package has a dependency, the whole package implicitly has that dependency, regardless of what the inner code might imply about installation status inside a Drupal site.
So basically your module needs a standard (not dev) require for the json-rpc module, and you can remove the composer.json from the submodule folder, as it won’t be doing anything.
